# Chrome (and Chromium) on Ubuntu 16.04 isn't opening downloads and doesn't show upload prompt

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome, downloads, upload

I'm using Chrome (but Chromium has the same issue). I'm not a power user, so don't know how to debug this.

When I click on any link to download anything it updates the launchbar icon (I have a number in circle indicating how many files it's "downloading", and I have a progress bar for it) but nothing else happens.. for a time.

After some time (sometimes 2h sometimes 5h, sometimes never tho..) it downloads it all.

The same with uploads - I click on the upload button.. nothing happens, then it happens all in same time - both downloads are ready, and I have n number of open upload prompts (where n ==  the number of times I clicked upload button somewhere ;-) even when the tabs are already closed ).

I have a SLI conf, with 2x 980Ti. I have 3 monitors. I have some other issues, that may be related, like: when I log in I have wrong desktops configuration, after 10-15s it flickers and it's how I set it up.

I'm using **nVidia proprietary 375.39 drivers** now (changed couple of days ago from **Nouveau - where I had the same problem**).

Sometimes **when the system loads I have compiz error** popping up.

- As I wrote above, I'm not a power user, so please let me know how can
  I get you more info on this problem to debug it.

Weird thing is that I have an Intel Stick Media Center with Ubuntu 16.04 and it has the same problem. I've tried deleting/changing extensions - now I only have **OneTab, GetPocket, RescueTime**.

I think it's something on the connection between triggering and event and unity reacting to it? Been dealing with it for couple of weeks.

TIA!